Why does the glfw window keep disappearing?
The code compiles ok:
#include <iostream>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

const GLuint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

const GLchar* vertexShaderSource = "Version 330 core\n"

                                   "layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"
                                   "void main()\n"
                                   "{\n"
                                   "gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);\n"
                                   "}\0";

const GLchar* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
                                     "out vec4 color;\n"
                                     "void main()\n"
                                     "{\n"
                                     "color = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
                                     "}\n";

int main()
{
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE );

    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE );

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow( WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Learn OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr );

    int screenWidth, screenHeight;

    glfwGetFramebufferSize( window, &screenWidth, &screenHeight );

    if( nullptr == window )
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create glfw window!\n";
        glfwTerminate();

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if( GLEW_OK != glewInit() )
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize glew!" << std::endl;

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    glViewport( 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight );
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader( GL_VERTEX_SHADER );
    glShaderSource( vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL );

    glCompileShader( vertexShader );
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog( 512 );

    glGetShaderiv( vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success );

    if( !success )
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog( vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog );
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }

    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER );
    glShaderSource( fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL );
    glCompileShader( fragmentShader );
    glGetShaderiv( fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success );

    if( !success )
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog( fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog );
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION::FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }

    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader( shaderProgram, vertexShader );
    glAttachShader( shaderProgram, fragmentShader );
    glLinkProgram( shaderProgram );

    glGetProgramiv( shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success );

    if( !success )
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog( shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog );
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING::FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }

    glDeleteShader( vertexShader );
    glDeleteShader( fragmentShader );

    GLfloat vertices[] = { -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f };

    GLuint VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &VAO );
    glGenBuffers( 1, &VBO );

    glBindVertexArray( VAO );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( vertices ), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof( GLfloat ), (GLvoid*)0 );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );

    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
    glBindVertexArray( 0 );

    while( !glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) )
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
        glClearColor( 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f );
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        glUseProgram( shaderProgram );
        glBindVertexArray( VAO );
        glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3 );
        glBindVertexArray( 0 );

        glfwSwapBuffers( window );
    }

    glDeleteVertexArrays( 1, &VAO );
    glDeleteBuffers( 1, &VBO );

    glfwTerminate();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

...but when I execute a.out the window appears for a split second then disappears again.
How can I make it stay there?
I am compiling on bodhi linux 5.15.0-78-generic
with g++ -lGLEW -lGL -lglfw

Unrelated, but you forgot glDeleteProgram after the render loop

Also, RE: inline GLSL, raw string literals are a thing.

infoLog is now declared as a single GLchar with the value (512 wrapped around to) 0, instead of an array of characters. This why there isn't an informative error message.

Have you checked the printed log? From the source code you provided, I see that the vertex shader should not compile. It begins with
Version 330 core\n

but must be
#version 330 core\n

Since you don't stop the program execution on error, when shader compilation failed, your program goes on, presents the window, runs glfwPollEvents, tries to render, and fails.
